# Google Fonts: How can I prevent Internet Explorer from rendering a bold font as regular?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-webfonts

Google Fonts is great. But, I seem to have a problem with Internet Explorer. A font (say, Arvo) styled as bold **won't render as bold in Internet Explorer**. It does in all other browsers though.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Some of us have to code for the other 65% of web users.  I don't have an answer to this question but your comment was just asine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about making an IE specific stylesheet and in it declare something like

`* { font-weight: regular; }`

It's usually not advised to use the `*` selector, so try to narrow it down to wherever the font is used. For example, perhaps it's just paragraph text: `p { font-weight: regular; }`, or just links: `a {...;}` etc. etc.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll go with an IE specific stylesheet and slab a different font in it. Something like that. :)